# Using Fused Location API and App Crashing Unexpectedly

Tags: java, android, fusedlocationproviderapi

I am using Google Fused Location API to get the current location of the device. For testing purposes, I am only saving the location to a `TextView`. I am calling the `LocationActivity` on Menu Select event but whenever I am clicking on the menu option, the app is crashing.

I have looked through the error log but did not get any success to resolve my problem. Please help me with that.

**Fetch Activity:**

```
public class LocationServiceActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

    Location mLocation;
    TextView latLng;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private static final int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private long UPDATE_INTERVAL = 15000;
    private long FASTEST_INTERVAL = 5000;

    private ArrayList permissionsToRequest;
    private ArrayList permissionsRejected = new ArrayList();
    private ArrayList permissions = new ArrayList();

    private final static int ALL_PERMISSIONS_RESULT = 101;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        latLng = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latLng);
        permissions.add(ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        permissions.add(ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
        permissionsToRequest = findUnAskedPermissions(permissions);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (permissionsToRequest.size() > 0)
                requestPermissions((String[]) permissionsToRequest.toArray(new String[permissionsToRequest.size()]), ALL_PERMISSIONS_RESULT);
        }
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
    }

    private ArrayList findUnAskedPermissions(ArrayList wanted) {
        ArrayList result = new ArrayList();

        for (Object perm : wanted) {
            if (!hasPermission((String) perm)) {
                result.add(perm);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (!checkPlayServices()) {
            latLng.setText("Please install Google Play services.");
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {


        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        mLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);


        if(mLocation!=null)
        {
            latLng.setText("Latitude : "+mLocation.getLatitude()+" , Longitude : "+mLocation.getLongitude());
        }

        startLocationUpdates();

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        if(location!=null)
            latLng.setText("Latitude : "+location.getLatitude()+" , Longitude : "+location.getLongitude());



    }

    private boolean checkPlayServices() {
        GoogleApiAvailability apiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
        int resultCode = apiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (apiAvailability.isUserResolvableError(resultCode)) {
                apiAvailability.getErrorDialog(this, resultCode, PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST)
                        .show();
            } else
                finish();

            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    protected void startLocationUpdates() {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enable Permissions", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);


    }

    private boolean hasPermission(String permission) {
        if (canMakeSmores()) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                return (checkSelfPermission(permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private boolean canMakeSmores() {
        return (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1);
    }


    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {

        switch (requestCode) {

            case ALL_PERMISSIONS_RESULT:
                for (Object perms : permissionsToRequest) {
                    if (!hasPermission((String) perms)) {
                        permissionsRejected.add(perms);
                    }
                }

                if (permissionsRejected.size() > 0) {


                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                        if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale((String) permissionsRejected.get(0))) {
                            showMessageOKCancel("These permissions are mandatory for the application. Please allow access.",
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                                            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                                                requestPermissions((String[]) permissionsRejected.toArray(new String[permissionsRejected.size()]), ALL_PERMISSIONS_RESULT);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                            return;
                        }
                    }

                }

                break;
        }

    }

    private void showMessageOKCancel(String message, DialogInterface.OnClickListener okListener) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(LocationServiceActivity.this)
                .setMessage(message)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", okListener)
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
                .create()
                .show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        stopLocationUpdates();
    }


    public void stopLocationUpdates()
    {
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
                    .removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

**Error Log:**

```
  --------- beginning of crash
2019-02-05 13:07:39.549 5653-5653/com.local.xspac.shopapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.local.xspac.shopapp, PID: 5653
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/Api$zzf;
        at com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at com.local.xspac.shopapp.LocationServiceActivity.onCreate(LocationServiceActivity.java:59)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.common.api.Api$zzf" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.local.xspac.shopapp-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.local.xspac.shopapp-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.local.xspac.shopapp-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.local.xspac.shopapp-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.local.xspac.shopapp-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.local.xspac.shopapp-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.local.xspac.shopapp-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.local.xspac.shopapp-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.local.xspac.shopapp-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.local.xspac.shopapp-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.local.xspac.shopapp-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.local.xspac.shopapp-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.local.xspac.shopapp-1/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices.<clinit>(Unknown Source) 
        at com.local.xspac.shopapp.LocationServiceActivity.onCreate(LocationServiceActivity.java:59) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

**Build.gradle (App Module):**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.local.xspac.shopapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    //adding volley library
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
    implementation files('libs/activation.jar')
    implementation files('libs/additionnal.jar')
    implementation files('libs/mail.jar')
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**Project Level Gradle:**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.common.api.Api$zzf" on path: DexPathList[[zip file 
         looks like you are missing a library on your classpath

Comment: I have implemented dependencies in `build.gradle` file: `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this **Dependencies**

**Project Gradle**

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
```

**App Gradle**

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.0.0'
```

Here is all dependencies you can use for location for latest versions

Comment: getting this error: `ERROR: The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement is being requested by various other libraries at [[15.0.1,15.0.1]], but resolves to 16.0.1. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.`

Comment: @Strange please add you Gradle files in question

Comment: @Strange use same versions for all dependencies for google

Comment: Project level gradle? @Strange

Comment: @Strange are you using older dependencies

Comment: @Strange I updated my answer and add what I am using for location.